# Use gsub to replace the word 'hi' . (see conditions posted below) - Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

For this string: `hi i am going on a hike, hi hiiiiiiiiiiiii!`.

Using gsub how would I replace all instances of `hi` with `bye`.

The criteria I need to fulfill are as follows:

- Only find the word 'hi' **not** substrings of other words (e.g 'hi'ke).
- If 'hi' is at the end of the string, (e.g hi. or hi!) consider that a match for 'hi', but don't chop off the punctuation.
- Count 'hiiiiiiii' (with n number of i's after the h) as 'hi'

After running gsub on the string It should look like this: `bye i am going on a hike, bye bye!`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"hi i am going on a hike, hi hiiiiiiiiiiiii!".gsub(/\bhi+\b/, "bye")
# => "bye i am going on a hike, bye bye!"
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to regex, your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: New I can understand, but at least show an attempt before you are handed a solution

Comment: @grail You are right. I just thought it was simpler to ask for an answer, rather than show what I was trying and risk confusing everyone.

Comment: @mtaff I always like to see any attempt as then I can help you with what you have tried and maybe correct the command you have tried to use instead of showing something you may have never seen and confuse you too :)